# A large image placed at top of page causes page-speed insights to complain

Tags: html, images, photo, text

I made a site that's basically a site asking people to vote for a person and the first page mostly shows a picture of a person which is what the site is about. Most of the text is underneath and scrolling is required to retrieve it.

Google then complains with:

> Prioritize visible content
>
> Your page requires additional network round trips to render the above-the-fold content. For best performance, reduce the amount of HTML needed to render above-the-fold content.
>
> The entire HTML response was not sufficient to render the above-the-fold content. This usually indicates that additional resources, loaded after HTML parsing, were required to render above-the-fold content. Prioritize visible content that is needed for rendering above-the-fold by including it directly in the HTML response.
>
> Only about 60% of the final above-the-fold content could be rendered with the full HTML response

Is there something I can add to an HTTP header or HTML to make google page-speed insights not put up this error about my site?

After all, visitors will want to know what the person looks like before taking any other action on the site which currently is a link to the voting page as well as a link for instructions on voting, and I doubt people will read the remaining text since the message is loud and clear in the large title itself which is the only thing above the picture.

Comment: Can you provide an example URL?

Comment: http://voteformoses.clubcatcher.com/

Comment: You always come up with the best questions!! In this case, can't you place the text and image side by side on non-mobile devices?? If you were to do that, I would put the vote button above the text.

Comment: Those are pages I whipped up fast tho. doing that involves programming in htaccess and/or PHP. I'll think about moving the vote button up. As it is now, google has no complaints about that page on a mobile device.

Comment: I can see your using a lot of inline CSS is that because its in prototype?

Comment: Its something I did quick and its something that won't last forever because voting closes soon

Answer (score 2):

The only issue I can see on that URL is that you're missing width and height attributes on the big image at the top. This means after getting the HTML page, the browser has to wait for the image to download and then re-render the page, since it has no way of knowing how much space to allow for the image until it has the whole file. That may be what Insights means by having to wait for 'additional resources' to render the above-the-fold content. (If you click on the 'see screenshot' option in the results that seems to back this up too.)

Since you have no other externally linked resources on that page (apart from images), if that doesn't fix it there's probably not much you can do.

Take the Insights report with a pinch of salt. In your question you said you wanted to fix this 'error', but Insights doesn't give errors, it gives suggestions. Tools like this can only analyse the code that is used to construct your page, they can't know semantically that the image is the main *subject* of the page. For that reason I would be very surprised if something like this was one of the factors that went into Google's SEO page speed algorithm (and even if it did, this site loads extremely fast and so wouldn't be affected).

Comment: _This means after getting the HTML page, the browser has to wait for the image to download and then re-render the page, since it has no way of knowing how much space to allow for the image until it has the whole file._ I think this piece of advice is what is giving me the exact same suggestion. Did not know that the browser is **re-rendering** the page after the image download if width and height for the image are not specified. These attributes have to be in the HTML alongside the `img` tag. Thank you for clearing that up!